# SQL Server Agent not to catch stderr/stdout from python

Tags: python, sql-server, exception, logging, agent

I have a CmdExec job in SQL Agent that runs Python application. Python itself writes JSON formatted logs to files and then Filebeat service transfers these logs to Elastic.

Everything works fine in case we have handled exception or system exit in Python script:

```
try:
    #something
except Exception:
    logging.exception("Some exception")
```

or

```
sys.exit(1)
```

The problem starts when script fails with unhandled exception. SQL Agent in this case catches the output, writes stack trace to internal msdb table and doesn't output anything to log files (and as result to Filebeat + Elastic).

Have you ever faced such thing? How to duplicate/keep this error in log file?

Answer (score 0):

Answer:
SQL Agent just gets sys.stderr output.
You need either override sys.stderr or use [sys.excepthook](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html) with custom function.